# SwiftUI / imagepicker / firebasefirestore - image uploads properly but does not refresh when leaving image picker view

Tags: xcode, swiftui, firebase-storage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have this settingview where the user can update their profile picture, which gets uploaded in Firebase Storage, and gets loaded as WebImage(url:ImageURL). It works, however when the user changes the profile image, it does not get immediately refreshed. They have to leave the screen and come back, then the loadImageFromFirebase function gets called and the new image is displayed properly.
I would like the new image to show as soon as it is selected and uploaded to Firebase Storage.

I have tried SDImageCache.shared.clearMemory() but that didn't really help (perhaps I didn't do it in the right place?)

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var settingsViewModel = SettingsViewModel()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @State private var presented = false
    @State private var isShowPhotoLibrary = false
    @State private var image = UIImage()
    @State private var imageURL = URL(string: "")

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        
        WebImage(url: imageURL)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 250.0, height: 250.0, alignment: .center)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
            .shadow(radius: 10)
            .scaledToFit()


        Text("Project")
          .font(.title)
          .fontWeight(.semibold)
        
        Form {
          Section {
            HStack {
              Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
              Text("Upload profile image")
              Spacer()
              Text("Plain")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.isShowPhotoLibrary = true
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $isShowPhotoLibrary) {
                    ImagePicker(sourceType: .photoLibrary, selectedImage: self.$image)
                }
                
            }
          }
          
      
          
          AccountSection(settingsViewModel: self.settingsViewModel)
        }
        
        .navigationBarTitle("Settings", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
          Button(action: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }) {
            Text("Done")
        })
        
      }
      .onAppear(perform: loadImageFromFirebase)
        
    }
 
  }
    func loadImageFromFirebase() {
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        guard let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let storageRef = storage.reference().child(userid+"/profilephoto"+"/profile.jpeg")
        storageRef.downloadURL {
            (url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            self.imageURL = url!
        }
    }
    
}
```

and the image picker:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
    
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return imagePicker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        
        var parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            
            if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.selectedImage = image
                uploadprofileImage(image: image)
            }

            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `SettingsView`: it seems your `image: UIimage` is updated by your `ImagePicker` but is not used in the `body`... You need a `Image(uiImage:)` view.

Comment: So the ImagePicker actually uploads the selected image on FirebaseFirestore using uploadprofileImage(image: image). Then the image on SettingsView is downloaded by WebImage(url: imageURL). When I leave the screen and come back, the image is loaded as intended because of .onAppear(perform: loadImageFromFirebase), however I'd like to reproduce this behavior when the ImagePicker is dismissed (once an image has been selected and we come back to SettingsView).

Comment: `ImagePicker` copies the `UIImage` (the user picked) in `@State private var image`. You have to display this UIImage. The SwiftUI View  `Image(uiImage:)`can help you. At the moment you only display a `WebImage` (from an url).

Comment: I think I see what you mean. If I understand correctly, when I select the image it gets displayed using UIImage, then if I leave the screen and come back, UIImage isn't displaying the screen anymore but it's fine because it gets displayed by WebImage instead.